# outsource.com - anyone believe this isn't a scam?

Tags: outsourcing

outsource.com - anyone believe this isn't a scam? outsource.com charges candidates to apply for jobs, then forces them to under-bid each other. I would welcome anyone who can provide the names of other Websites like this. outsource.com - anyone believe this isn't a scam?

Answer (score 0):

I found this article with some sites that might help.

http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/245953

The outsouce.com jobs sound interesting, but yes I agree  the model skews towards clients and outsource.com rather than the freelancers. I just got off the phone with them to confirm that if I signed up, I was on the hook for 12 months... not ready to make that commitment without a test-drive of at least one or two months.

I was told to go check reviews and see how great they were, and I came across this site and there seems to be many people who are concerned and wary.

If they had an option to try it for two months, I would do that.